# Как правильно подключать клиентское приложение к базе данных?

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, postgresql

Очень часто мне приходится подключать приложения (например, wpf) к базе данных. В примерах и в задачах чаще всего это подключение происходит либо через учётную запись windows, либо, господи помилуй, через sa пользователя.

как же правильно производить подключение к базе данных?

Мои предположения заключаются в том, что для каждой роли клиентского приложения необходимо создать свою учётную запись с правами на сервере.

Как, например, подключение происходит у приложения "вконтакте"? Я думаю, что у них есть определённая учётная запись базы данных, а администраторы копаются в ней уже через свою, с полными правами.

Правка 1: В данном случае я имею в виду роли БД. Т.е. на стороне сервера должна создаваться роль, определённая для приложения. По моим предположениям, в строке подключения к базе данных я могу прописать соответствующие логин и пароль. (Если я конечно в правильном направлении)

Comment: Что для вас является "подключением клиента"? Вот на примере ВК, о каком подключение идет речь? Мы с вами являемся клиентами? Если да, то у нас не должно быть доступа вообще к базе, мы не должны знать ее IP, не должны знать пароль, у нас не должно быть в базе учетной записи. Весь наш доступ осуществляется через посредника, сервер, он один подключен к базе, а наружу отдает "органы управления", через которые мы с вами можем получить, например данные о себе, которые хранятся в базе.

Comment: Если нет, и речь именно про "администрирование", то зависит от вашей архитектуры, конечно на 1 человека 1 аккаунт, со своими ограниченными правами, чтобы, например кто-то другой не мог изменить пароль, системные настройки или что-либо еще, а лишь мог изменить те данные, за которые он отвечает.

Comment: вам нужно сделать API интерфейс к ней, в котором уже можно настроить и роли и ограничения. В c# можно это реализовать через ASP.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваше предположение верно.

Часто создают, как минимум две учетных записи для ролей:

1. Application - имеет право читать и писать данные.
2. Deployer - может выполнять DDL. Используется на этапе разворачивания приложения и при установке новых версий, когда нужно запускать миграции.

Если приложение состоит из нескольких разных компонентов, то роль Application может быть еще поделена, например, если у приложения есть админка, то там может использоваться отдельная учетная запись, к которой есть права изменения в таблицах конфигурации самого приложения. Для модуля отчетов может быть создана отдельная учетка с правами только на чтение и т.д.

Администраторы БД используют отдельные учетные записи, у которых прав побольше. В организациях, которые серьезно относятся к безопасности, встречал подход, когда для расследований проблем на проде, ответственным разработчикам дают права только на чтение, а если нужно что-то исправить, то добавляют прав кратковременно.

Comment: Я бы еще дополнил, что прямое подключение клиентского приложения в БД - не очень хорошая затея. А хорошая затея - иметь к примеру API сервер.

Comment: Конечно. Я вопрос понимаю так, что "клиентское приложение", это имеется ввиду клиентское по отношению к БД и в этом ключе отвечал. Хотя сейчас вижу, что речь о десктопном приложении, а мой ответ о серверном.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно - это так, чтобы вы могли контролировать кто имеет досуп к БД (аутенификация) и что он там может делать (авторизация).

Например, если у вас настольное WPF приложение, которое лезет само напрямую в БД (что само по себе не лучшее решение), то единтвенный способ для вас контролировать кто и что может делать с БД - это контроль на уровне пользователей и прав вашей БД. То есть либо каждый юзер сам вводит свой логин/пароль (БД аутенификация), либо используется доменная аутентификация + БД-авторизация.

Если же у вас вебсайт, то есть конечный юзер может даже никогда и не узнать, что вообще используется какая либо БД, то тут 2 варианта:

- Имперсонализация, когда учетные данные пользователя используются для доступа к БД. Такое распрострнанено в интранете - частных корпоративных сетях, когда пул пользователей конечен и управляется централизованно. Обычно такое просят безопасники, которые хотят знать все действия юзера вплоть до транзакций.
- Более рспространенный вариант - использовать данные аутенификации юзера для его авторизации уже на вашем сайте/сервисе. То есть сайт решит, какие юзеру доступны операции, но при этом сам сайт ходит в БД под какой то единой записью для всего сайта. Такая схема широко используется как на публичных веб сайтах, так и во всяких микросервисах, где каждый микросервис (которых может быть сотни, и соответсвенно, баз данных тоже может быть сотни) сам уже решает, что юзер может делать, а что не может. Это позволяет снизить нагрузку на БД, так как БД больше не парится по поводу юзеров и их прав. К примеру, в микросервисной архитектуре, где может быть множетство баз данных, будет расточительно хранить каждого юзера в каждой из БД.